# 3D objects with projections of constant area

Tags: mg.metric-geometry

Objects of constant width are well-known, and I have in my hand a (non-spherical) solid of constant diameter.  The question arises:

Are there any non-spherical 3-dimensional objects such that their orthogonal projections are always the same area?

Most objects are such that as you turn them their shadow changes in area, but is this always the case, except for the sphere?  This seems such an obvious question that I thought it must have been asked, and if asked, then either trivially answered, or well-known as an open question.  However, moderate searches have failed to find any references.

Has anyone here studied this?

Comment: what is the non-spherical solid of constant diameter in your hand?

Comment: These are bodies of constant brightness, and I believe they have come up in previous questions here.

Comment: http://www.math.sc.edu/~howard/Reprints/published_brightness.pdf

Comment: What do you mean by "objects"? Subsets? Surfaces? Convex subsets?

Comment: @Yoav it helps to give a link... http://mathoverflow.net/questions/138525/a-question-about3-3-dimensional-convex-bodies

Comment: @MohammadF.Tehrani: I have a Reuleaux Triangle that has been spun around an axis. I have also seen a tetrahedral equivalent to the Reuleaux Triangle, but I do not own one.

Comment: @Misha: I mean a closed convex subset of R^3.

Comment: @Yoav: Thank you - I have now searched that term, but there seems very little available on-line.  I will search further.