# A claim on planar sections of 3D convex bodies

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, convex-geometry

Ref: [More on shadows of 3D convex bodies](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/450249/more-on-shadows-of-3d-convex-bodies),

[Shadows and planar sections of polyhedra](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/402665/shadows-and-planar-sections-of-polyhedra)

Given a 3D convex body C, we define a maximal area (perimeter) section of C with respect to any specified direction $n$ in space as the maximum area (perimeter) planar section with $n$ normal to the plane of section. Is the following claim valid?

- If all maximal perimeter sections of C have equal perimeter, then, C is a sphere.

([Convex bodies with constant maximal section function in odd dimensions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/70391/convex-bodies-with-constant-maximal-section-function-in-odd-dimensions) discusses the corresponding claim with all max area cross sections of C having same area).

Note: One can also possibly think of convex bodies such that all maximal area sections have same perimeter and vice versa.